# Thred safe data structure for holding client information

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, dictionary, pthreads

I am writing an application in which the server has to keep track of connections from multiple clients. Each client is assigned a connection id which it sends in every packet for identification. I want to map the connection id to the client information. Earlier, I was using std::map but I found that it wasnt thread safe.  I need a container that can support this functionality in plain C++03. No 3rd party libraries allowed(using lab equipment). Failing this, please tell me how I can achieve this using std::map and some kind of locking

Let us call the data structure info.There are 2 threads running, (for sending & receiving respectively).  They perform the following operations on info:-

```
recv_thread {
  //read id
  if(id == 0) info.insert(0,clientdata);
  else {
       do stff, update info[id]
}

send_thread { 
     for each key in info:
       if (key==0) {
          delete info[0];
          info.insert(connid, clientdata);
       }
       else {
           update info[key]
           if(client taking too long) delete info[key];
       }
 }
```

Comment: If you are using C++11, consider examining http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Comment: Nope. Maybe I should have added, ancient lab computers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use __sync_fetch_and_add to get the next connid and use pthread mutex to wrap your other map calls.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int nextConnid = 1;
...
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
...
recv_thread {
  //read id
  if(id == 0) 
    info.insert(__sync_fetch_and_add(&nextConnid, 1), clientdata);
  else {
       do stff, 
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
       update info[id]
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

send_thread { 
     for each key in info:
           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
           update info[key]
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
           if(client taking too long) delete info[key];

 }
```

Comment: this looks non-standard to me? but i'm looking for an answer like this one

Comment: @Bug Catcher - the "standard" approach would be a wrapper class using the map as a base and using the mutex to synchronize the method calls.

Comment: Actually I generate a random connection id so the sync isnt necessary, and maybe this solution would not be sufficient as the map iterator may become invalid due to insertion while iterating over keys?

Comment: @Bug Catcher - You would simply wrap the whole "for each in map" blaock with the mutex lock/unlock.

Answer (score 1):

See the example: -

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

for creating a std::map using mutex

Answer (score 0):

you have to protect your container by mutex. depending on what api you use for starting threads, it will be pthread_mutex_t or std :: mutex